# Can't deploy Firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am new to using Firebase functions and I have been following this tutorial on setting it up:
https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/angular4-transactional-email-with-cloud-functions-and-sendgrid/
but when I try to deploy it using

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

I get the following error

```
    Running command: C:\Users\fjral\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\.bin\cross-env npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build
npm ERR! missing script: build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\fjral\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-08T20_09_37_587Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

I see that it says missing script: build, but I'm not sure where to find this, or how to replace/fix the issue.

Comment: It sounds like your main `firebase.json` makes a pre-deploy call to a `build` step, but that script is then not defined in the `functions/firebase.json`.

Comment: do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: Try removing the `predeploy` from `firebase.json`.

Comment: removing the predeploy worked thanks

Comment: I had the same issue, but any of my firebase.json files that exist would have been automatically created.  Do you know how auto-generated files like these would end up in a state where they don't work?