# Error during deploy functions to Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

**The error**

```
code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npm --prefix "D:\\Project\\Web\\functions" run lint',
  path: 'npm --prefix "D:\\Project\\Web\\functions" run lint',
  spawnargs: []
}

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"%RESOURCE_DIR%\" run lint"
    ]
  }
}
```

I got the above error when I trying run the `firebase deploy` command, I searched the whole internet and I find related issues but not helpful so what is the problem?

I'm using Windows 10

**Edit**

[image]

Comment: Is there any information about the error before `code: 'ENOENT',` part ?

Comment: @Berci Check Now

Comment: @ofTHIS Usually the ENOENT error occurs when the compiler cannot find a file or directory. Can you check if the firestore.rules and firestore.indexes.json are accessible by the script?

Comment: @davidbilla Unfortunately, I'm an android developer, Not a web developer but I have a little bit of experience in the web so could you clarify what should I do?

Comment: The error seems to suggest that npm was not found (see https://github.com/moxystudio/node-cross-spawn/blob/master/lib/enoent.js). Have you made sure that npm is on your PATH? try running `npm --version` from a command line

Comment: @jfhr I got this 7.20.3

Comment: I think you could try deleting the node modules and reinstall them (with npm install). Additionally  try to check that you are using the same node version as the project.

Comment: What is the node version you are using? There are some deprecated versions also,  according to [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version), Unsupported versions also may cause the issue. 
Have you tried removing the predeploy from firebase.json? According to  Michael Bleigh comment in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49181706/cant-deploy-firebase-functions#:~:text=Try%20removing%20the,Michael%20Bleigh) may solve your issue.

Comment: I removed predeploy from firebase.json and worked with me. Thanks Guys for your time

Answer (score 0):

Removing `predeploy` from firebase.json will solve the issue. Remove “npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint” as shown below.

**firebase.json**

<strike>"predeploy": [</strike>

<strike>"npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint"</strike>

<strike>]</strike>

In some cases, the issue could be due to unsupported node versions. As per [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version) Node.js 8 is deprecated. Make sure you are using supported versions.